# Automatically expand bullet list to tree structure while typing

Tags: vim, tree, indentation

I would like to do as below:

- like a kind of bullet list/text mind map, with connected branches instead of empty space
- must be automatic
- must be displayed as I type (unlike substite)
- must be printable
- must be characters (so that it is visible by other people with a normal text editor)

  ```
  text
     ├──────text
     |         └──────text
     └──────text
  ```

I tried the following:

- indent guide plugin: if I replace in the config file more than one symbol, it doesn't work
- `:%substitute/    \ze\S/└── /`: it works, but only after the whole text is written. I need it to be done instantly, while typing. And it does not display really a tree structure (`├`), just `└──`.
- mapping `*` to `└──`: it kind of works; but it is not automatic (I need to indent, then type the bullet); moreover there is discontinuity of vertical lines if I write more than one sublevels.

I am not sure if nerdtree works for this purpose.

How can I do this in Vim?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, thank you for your question, it took some time, it I had fun writing a few syntax rules to achieve the result you wanted!

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Example]

[image: Demo Gif]

---

And here's the code I've been using:

```
function! MakeSynTree()
    IndentLinesDisable
    set cocu=nvic
    call clearmatches()

    let tablen = &tabstop

    exe 'syntax match MainLine "\v^%( {'.tablen.'})+\S@=" contains=Jumps,MainNode'

    exe 'syntax match MainNode "\v %( {'.(tablen-1).'}\S)@=" conceal cchar=├ contained nextgroup=Horiz1'
    exe 'syntax match EndNode  "\v %( {'.(tablen-1).'}\S)@=" conceal cchar=└ contained nextgroup=Horiz1'

    exe 'syntax match JustSpaces " \{'.(tablen-1).'}" contained'
    let cnt = 1
    while cnt < tablen-1
        let grp_name = 'Horiz'.(cnt+1)
        if cnt == tablen-2 | let grp_name = 'HorizLast' | endif
        exe 'syntax match Horiz'.cnt.' " " conceal cchar=─ contained nextgroup='.grp_name
        let cnt += 1
    endwhile
    syntax match HorizLast " " contained

    let cnt = 0
    let jump_names = []
    while cnt < 10
        call add(jump_names, 'Jump'.cnt)
        exe 'syntax match Jump'.cnt.' "\v%(^ {'.cnt*tablen.'})@<= {'.tablen.'}%(.*\n%(%( {'.(cnt+1)*tablen.'}).*\n)*^ {'.(cnt+1)*tablen.'}\S)@=" contained contains=Updown'
        exe 'syntax match EndLine'.cnt.' "\v^ {'.(cnt+1)*tablen.'}\S(.*\n%(%( {'.(cnt+1)*tablen.'}).*\n)*^ {'.(cnt+1)*tablen.'}\S)@!" contains=Jumps,EndNode'
        let cnt += 1
    endwhile
    exe 'syntax match Jumps "\v%( {'.tablen.'})+%( {'.tablen.'}\S)@=" contained contains='.join(jump_names, ',')

    syntax match Updown " " conceal cchar=│ contained nextgroup=JustSpaces
    syntax match Blank " " contained nextgroup=JustSpaces
endfunction
function EraseSyncTree()
    syntax clear Updown
    syntax clear Blank
    syntax clear HorizLast
    syntax clear Jumps
    syntax clear MainNode
    syntax clear EndNode
endfunction
function ReplaceChar(str, pos, char)
    let out = ''
    if a:pos > 0 | let out .= a:str[: a:pos - 1] | endif
    let out .= a:char
    if a:pos < len(a:str) | let out .= a:str[a:pos + 1 :] | endif
    return out
endfunction
function! MakeRealTree()
    sil!%s/[─├└│]/ /g
    call MakeSynTree()
    call cursor(1, 1)

    " Line per line
    while 1
        let offset = 0

        call search('^ ', 'cW')
        let line = getline('.')
        " Char per char
        while 1
            let col = col('.')
            let syn_group = map(synstack(line('.'), col), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name" )')[-1]
            let char = ' '
            if match(syn_group, 'Horiz\d') >= 0
                let char = '─'
            endif
            if match(syn_group, 'Updown') >= 0
                let char = '│'
            endif
            if match(syn_group, 'MainNode') >= 0
                let char = '├'
            endif
            if match(syn_group, 'EndNode') >= 0
                let char = '└'
            endif
            let line = ReplaceChar(line, col-1 + offset, char)
            if index(['├','└','│','─'], char) >= 0
                " Those are special character, they take up more space than
                " they seem..
                let offset += 2
            endif
            if ! search('\%#.\zs ') | break | endif
        endwhile
        call setline(line('.'), line)
        call cursor(line('.') + 1, 1)
    endwhile
    call EraseSyncTree()
endfunction

autocmd FileType txt call DrawMeATree()
```

I paired it with the `txt` files, but you can use the `MakeSynTree()` function in any file, to draw trees!

---

The usage is simple:

1. Open a file
2. Use the syntax function (`:call MakeSynTree()`)
3. Write whatever you want, make trees!
   At this point, the "tree" is only visual, the characters are not in the actual document.
4. Once you're happy with your tree, and you're ready to print it, make it real using `:call MakeRealTree()`
5. Warning, this will make the tree real, and it *won't be updated in real time anymore*

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello Zorzi,
1- big thank you for your time, happy you got fun :)
2- I am new to all of this: should I put this code inside vimrc?
3- when you mean high candy: if I have to print the file, will the tree structure be displayed? if not, is there a way to do so with this code? if not, is it possible with another solution?
4- thanks again :)

Comment: For it to work, yes, you should stick that in your vimrc. Then it should launch automatically in `txt` files. If you want to enable it in other files, just hit `:``call DrawMeATree()``enter`.  If you print the file, the tree structure won't show, and there's no simple way to make a real tree from this code.. But let me some time, I'll add to my answer to draw a real tree :)